# Is Flame Wisp cumulative with itself?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e, stacking

I cast [Flame Wisp](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=912), than hit with a Strike. Now I have 2 wisps. What happens if I cast Flame Wisp again?

1. The new one overrides the old one, I have 3 wisps
2. The new one is added to the old one, I have 6 wisps (the old one regains, as I just cast a fire spell)
3. As 2, but every time I hit with a Strike, 2 wisps damages the target

I assume it is *option 3*, but could argue for 1 as well. Which is it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Command spell cast twice (PF2e)](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/180691/command-spell-cast-twice-pf2e)

Comment: @ESCE how does that solve this question?

Comment: @Akixkisu both are just duplicate effects on the same target. I suppose https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/153423/is-it-possible-to-benefit-from-multiple-shield-spells might also work, but the duplicate effects answer isn't the top answer there, so the first question made more sense to me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### The new (or higher level) effect takes priority.

The [Pathfinder 2E General Rules](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=312) state that duplicates of the same effect (such as a spell with overlapping duration) do not stack.

> Duplicate Effects
>
> **When you’re affected by the same thing multiple times, only one instance applies, using the higher level of the effects, or the newer effect if the two are the same level.**  For example, if you were using *mage armor* and then cast it again, you’d still benefit from only one casting of that spell. Casting a spell again on the same target might get you a better duration or effect if it were cast at a higher level the second time, but otherwise doing so gives you no advantage.

When you re-cast *flame wisp*, you will have 3 wisps. One and only one wisp will hit a target when you successfully Strike them while the spell is active. This can still be useful if you have already used up some of the wisps from a previous casting.